# How to create a range of IP addresses?

Tags: php

Suppose the input is:

`222.123.34.45` and `222.123.34.55`

then I need to output the ip address in between them:

```
222.123.34.45 222.123.34.46 ... 222.123.34.55
```

Comment: Does only the last octet vary?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`ip2long()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) and [`long2ip()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.long2ip.php):

```
function ip_range($from, $to) {
  $start = ip2long($from);
  $end = ip2long($to);
  $range = range($start, $end);
  return array_map('long2ip', $range);
}
```

The above turns the two IP addresses into numbers (using PHP core functions), creates a range of numbers and then turns that number range into IP addresses.

If you want them separated by spaces just `implode()` the result.

Comment: +1 for pointing out three functions i'd never seen before.  Might be better just to iterate `$start` to `$end` rather than potentially creating gigantic arrays.

Comment: It's one of the great things about PHP: there are functions for almost everything already.

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging PHP's type flexibility

Leveraging the fact that IP Addresses are actually numbers (may do weird things on

$ip2 = '222.123.34.55';

```
$ips = array();
for($i=ip2long($ip);$i<=ip2long($ip2);$i++)
{
    $ips[] = long2ip($i);
}

print_r($ips);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function;
$ipStr = "192.168.1.0/255";

```
 function getIpsArrayFromStrRange($ipStr) {
    $ipsArray = array();
    //validate ip and check range existing
    $regexp = '/^(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})(\/(\d{1,3}))?$/';
    $matches = array();
    if(preg_match($regexp,$ipStr,$matches)){


        //if it is a range
        if(isset($matches[6])){
            $min_ip = min($matches[4],$matches[6]);
            $max_ip = max($matches[4], $matches[6]);
            for($i=$min_ip; $i<=$max_ip; $i++){
                $ipsArray[] = "$matches[1].$matches[2].$matches[3].$i";
            }   
        }else{
            $ipsArray[] = $ipStr;
        }
        return $ipsArray;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```