# How to merge array of ip in PHP to obtain the IP ranges?

Tags: php, arrays, ip

I have an array of ip like bellow:

```
array('10.1.48.0', '10.2.48.0', '10.3.48.0', ... '10.20.48.0', 
'10.22.48.0', ... , '10.85.48.0');
```

How can I detect and merge ip addresses as shown bellow:

```
array('10.1-20.48.0','10.22-85.48.0')
```

Like above, the result should be ranges of ip addresses that increase as same rules without any gap inside them

Comment: @JayBlanchard - the OP is looking to build ranges of IP addresses (or for someone to do it for them by the looks of things)

Comment: Ah, I see that now. Back to the coffee @NevStokes!

Comment: @JayBlanchard I need range of IP Addresses I dont want to omit duplicates

Comment: Can you share what you've tried @Alireza41?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: How do you know a range? What makes `10.1-20.48.0` the correct range over `10.1-85.48.0` or `10.1-3.48.0`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a range of IP addresses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938162/how-to-create-a-range-of-ip-addresses)

Comment: Why people just down vote without even reading the question carefully??

Comment: @chris85 Because i  10.4.48.0, 10.5.48.0, 10.6.48.0 , ... 10.20.48.0 presents in array but 10.21.48.0 is not

Comment: Because the OP showed no effort @cyberboy.

Comment: There are 6 IP ranges is your array. How do you know to pair the first value with the fourth value over any of the other ranges?

Comment: @chris85 - there are more than six IP addresses in the array — the `...` notation is being used to show that certain items have been omitted for brevity.

Comment: Yea, well of the 6 we can see...

Answer (score 0):

I'd attack this by building a four-dimensional array (exploding on the dots) and then rebuilding, looking for sequences within each dimension.

Comment: Don't you think this more of a comment than an answer?

Comment: It's an answer insofar as it answers the question "how can I..?"

Answer (score 0):

Use `ip2long()` and `long2ip()`:

```
function ip_range($from, $to) {
  $start = ip2long($from);
  $end = ip2long($to);
  $range = range($start, $end);
  return array_map('long2ip', $range);
}
```

The above turns the two IP addresses into numbers (using PHP core functions), creates a range of numbers and then turns that number range into IP addresses.

If you want them separated by spaces just implode() the result.

As seen in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938162/how-to-create-a-range-of-ip-addresses)

Comment: If you're going to copy an answer why not just mark the question as a duplicate?

Comment: This also doesn't do quite what the OP is after. Looks like he wants shorthand for ranges, not all values *in* a range